Having trouble installing and enrolling the fingerprint reader in Ubuntu 24.04
I can't install or enroll the fingerprint reader while in Windows it is working properly. This is my terminal output.
$ sudo apt install fprintd libfprint-2-2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
fprintd is already the newest version (1.94.3-1).
fprintd set to manually installed.
libfprint-2-2 is already the newest version (1:1.94.7+tod1-0ubuntu5~24.04.1).
libfprint-2-2 set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp libjs-async libjs-events libjs-inherits libjs-is-typedarray
  libjs-prettify libjs-regenerate libjs-source-map libjs-sprintf-js
  libjs-typedarray-to-buffer libnss3-tools libre2-10 libssl-dev libuv1-dev

$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04f2:b5ab Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 138a:0097 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0316 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card Reader
yaga@yaga-ThinkPad-T470s:~$ fprintd-enroll
Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available

It says No devices available while I use Windows in the same device and the fingerprint reader is working perfectly

Restart the fprintd service to see if it helps
